# Model the TSP as a shortest path

Tags: modeling, network-flow, traveling-salesman

We have a directed graph $G=(N,A)$  where $N$ are the verticies $N=0,1,2,3,4,5,..,n$ the starting location is node 0.
For each arc $a=i-j$ in A we have a distance $d_a>0$
So we want to start and end at 0 in a cycle.

Model the TSP as a shortest path problem. Create a modified directed graph.

I am not sure how to do this. The only thing I can think of is start from 0 find the shortest path which has all the node say to $u$ and then do $u-0$

Comment: I also know if we have (0,1) in the regular graph we have (0,1) in the modified graph and we have 2 0 nodes and 2 1 nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to create a node $(S,u)$ for each subset $S\subseteq N$ and last-visited city $u\in N$.  The main arcs are from $(S,u)$ to $(S\cup\{v\},v)$, with cost $d_{u,v}$.  You also need an arc from each $(N,u)$ to a dummy sink node, with cost $d_{u,0}$.  The problem is to find a shortest path from source $(\{0\},0)$ to sink.